# NSLayoutManager boundingRect(forGlyphRange:in:) returns wrong value for RTL languages

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, localization, hebrew

In my app, I draw custom background under lines of text in `UITextView`. To do so, I use `boundingRect(forGlyphRange:in:)` method of `NSLayoutManager`. It works well for LTR languages (Latin, Cyrillic, Chinese etc):
[image]
But if I use it for RTL texts (Hebrew, Farsi etc), the method returns wrong bounding rect (see padding on the left edge):
[image]

These additional paddings seem to have some logic. The first character determines the size of the padding for a line:
[image]

What the reason for this extra padding and how to get the correct bounding rect?

Here is a demo: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bpsr7bhhd7gqm2z/hebrew.zip?dl=0

UPD: seems this function gives a wrong result for all alphabets that use, I don't know how it's called, mutating characters. Devanagari for example:

[image]

Comment: I tried running our solution project and could get it to match your solution screenshot. Are you sure your solution project is correct?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ModDA.png)